# numerical methods for ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am working on this equation:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=Ax+b$$
$$c'x=d$$

Where $x$ is a vector ,A is a constant matrix, b c  are constant vectors. d is a constant number.

i.e. $c_1x_1(t)+\cdots+c_nx_n(t)=d$ for all $t$

How to numerical solve such a ODE?

Note that $t\ge 0$,but there is no information for $x(0)$.

Any help or reference is appreciated!

Comment: Actually it looks like it does not always _have_ a solution.  What if $c' A = 0$ but $c' b \neq 0$?  Multiplying the ODE on the left by $c'$ gives $c' x'(t) = c'A x(t) + c'b = c' b \neq 0$, but the equation $c' x(t) = d$ for all $t$ means $c' x'(t) = 0$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to build a generic solution to your problem, like solving $n+1$ IVPs
$$
\frac{dx^{(0)}}{dt} = Ax^{(0)} + b\\
x^{(0)}_i(0) = 0\\
\frac{dx^{(k)}}{dt} = Ax^{(k)}, \qquad k = 1, \dots, n\\
x^{(k)}_i(0) = \delta_{ik}
$$
So the ODE has a solution
$$
x(t) = x^{(0)}(t) + \sum_k C_k x^{(k)}(t)
$$
with $C_k$ being unknown. Next plug that solution into your constraint $c^\mathsf{T} x(t) = b$ and solve it in least squares sense for $C_k$
$$
\int_0^T \left(b - c^\mathsf{T} \big(x^{(0)}(t) + \sum_k C_k x^{(k)} (t)\big)\right)^2 dt \rightarrow \min_{C_k}
$$

But it seems that your problem would have a solution in very specific conditions.